# changing the GUI with a thread in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I have a JavaFX code in which I need to get input from a client in a new thread(because I should wait for the client until he sends me data) and when the data is correct I should show something in the GUI.

but how can I do this??

I can't use thread because in threads we can't change the GUI.

I can't use Platform.runLater too because if we have a long loop in Platform.runLater the GUI would be not responding.

so what is the solution?

Comment: Check out the [JavaFX concurrency trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: Execute the long-running code in the background thread, and from the background thread wrap *only* the code that changes the UI (which does not take a long time to run) in `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: Show your code where you are having the issue.

Comment: @James_D solution solved my problem